# Sitecore - Exclude items from full site publish

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

I am trying to find the best mechanism to flag items (which are currently being edited) to prevent them from going live during a full site publish.  I don't want to use the built in "Never Publish" as this will un-publish the item, whereas i want the current item to stay live. We are not using workflow elsewhere, so putting it on every item for this feels excessive. We are using 7.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to put the workflow on "Every" item, just set it on standard value of item template, and it will be assigned to all items.

I can't think of any other way than using sitecore workflow, this is how how Sitecore works.

Answer (score 2):

Workflows if your best bet, you can change the workflow steps to go directly from `Draft` to `Approved` if you want o avoid the `Awaiting Publish` step. You only need to set the workflow on the Standard Values of a base template that all other templates inherit.

Once you have workflow enabled, Sitecore will also automatically version Items. This allows you to set the Publishable flag on individual versioned Items.

If you don't want to use workflows for some reason, you can also create a new version of an Item from the Versions tab. Uncheck the Publishable option of the latest version until you are ready (from the Publish tab > Restrictions > Change).

[image: Publish Settings]
[image: Publish Item Notification]